# Bezug von "das" mit "eines der Dinge"

Tags: grammar, relative-clause

Hier ist eine typische Konstruktion:

> (a) Das ist eines der Dinge, die wir gestern gesehen haben.

Man überlege sich den folgenden Satz:

> (b) Das ist eines der Dinge, **das** wir gestern gesehen haben.

Kann man Satz (b) rechtfertigen mit dem Grund, dass sich **das** auf **eines** bezieht? Ich weiß, dass (b) auf jeden Fall lange nicht so typisch wie (a) ist. Es geht in dieser Frage darum, ob es *überhaupt* möglich ist, (b) als richtig zu sehen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Der Nebensatz schließt an *Dinge* an, somit muss jegliche Fortsetzung im Plural stehen.

Wenn sich der Nebensatz auf *eines* bezöge, wäre die Erwähnung der anderen *Dinge* überflüssig. Gleichzeitig wäre dann aber die Konstruktion mit *eines* an sich sinnlos - Widerspruch. Einzig richtig:

> Das ist eines der Dinge, die wir gestern gesehen haben.